# Concurrency, Atomicty, and Isolation in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, transactions, ef-code-first, isolation-level

Based on some periodically and concurrently incoming data, I'm performing an operation that will either insert a new row into a table, or update an existing row in the same table. Whether it inserts or updates a row is dependent on the states of the existing rows. So, the result of this operation will be affected by previous runs of this operation, and affect subsequent runs. I need to ensure atomicity/isolation using transactions, or locks, or something. There seems to be so many options and caveats with Entity Framework (and I'm a complete newbie with database stuff in general too) that I have no idea what direction I should be headed. TransactionScope, BeginTransaction, ambient transactions? Serializable or RepeatableRead? SaveChanges and AcceptAllChanges? Do I even need to do anything special? The fact that a new row can be added makes me worry especially about phantom rows, though I barely understand what that means. Any guidance on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial may be helpful to you - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Quote:

> **Pessimistic Concurrency (Locking)**
>
> If your application does need to prevent accidental data loss in
>   concurrency scenarios, one way to do that is to use database locks.
>   This is called pessimistic concurrency. For example, before you read a
>   row from a database, you request a lock for read-only or for update
>   access. If you lock a row for update access, no other users are
>   allowed to lock the row either for read-only or update access, because
>   they would get a copy of data that's in the process of being changed.
>   If you lock a row for read-only access, others can also lock it for
>   read-only access but not for update. Managing locks has some
>   disadvantages. It can be complex to program. It requires significant
>   database management resources, and it can cause performance problems
>   as the number of users of an application increases (that is, it
>   doesn't scale well). For these reasons, not all database management
>   systems support pessimistic concurrency. The Entity Framework provides
>   no built-in support for it, and this tutorial doesn't show you how to
>   implement it.
>
> **Optimistic Concurrency**
>
> The alternative to pessimistic concurrency is optimistic concurrency.
>   Optimistic concurrency means allowing concurrency conflicts to happen,
>   and then reacting appropriately if they do. For example, John runs the
>   Departments Edit page, changes the Budget amount for the English
>   department from $350,000.00 to $100,000.00. (John administers a
>   competing department and wants to free up money for his own
>   department.)*

There are code examples for both models in the in the tutorial.